# Where did my close votes go?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Once again, regarding [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/319/are-dice-really-necessary) on the main site. I haven't looked at it in a while, but at one point there were 3 votes to close on it.

I've been a member of Stack Overflow since it was first public, and don't remember close votes ever "expiring." Do they, and I perhaps just never noticed/knew? Because right now, there are no close votes, and according to the [revision history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/319/revisions), it never was closed and reopened.

Comment: [I miss my down votes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14048/i-miss-my-downvotes)... [I miss my close votes](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198/where-did-my-close-votes-go)... get a new song to sing! :P

Comment: LOL! To be fair, I missed the [downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59084/) I *cast*, not the ones I received. :) Here I'm missing close votes I received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Close (and re-open) votes indeed age away (after 4 days). The premise is that, if they didn't, the occasional close-votes that tend to accumulate randomly would close many, many questions over a long enough period of time. So they age away.

Reference: [Reopen votes disappeared - bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53702/reopen-votes-disappeared-bug)

Comment: Thanks for the official word. Never noticed it before -- maybe because we tend to close *fast* on SO. :)

Answer (score 3):

Close votes age away.  I believe it's two days.  I'm looking on meta for a source, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: I did the same, to no avail. When was this implemented ? I don't recall it.

Comment: Is that true of all the Stack Exchange sites or only Area 51s in Beta or.. ?

Comment: I know it was happening on Gaming recently.  I don't know for sure about SO, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this is very unusual. delete votes expire, but close votes should not, unless they changed it recently.